# jQuery - UTM script causing duplicate links

Tags: jquery, utm

I have the following UTM script which maintains UTM parameters across all links as visitors navigate to different pages. It seems when a link already has a "?" then the script causes links to  duplicate. Any help would be appreciated to prevent the duplicate links. Thanks in advance.

```
            <script type="text/javascript">
                (function() {
                    function utmParams(name) {
                        name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
                        var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
                            results = regex.exec(location.search);
                        return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
                    }
                    var utmArray = ['utm_campaign','utm_medium','utm_source','utm_content','utm_term'];
                    for (var i = 0; i < utmArray.length; i++) {
                        if (window.location.href.indexOf(utmArray[i]) > -1) {
                            $('a').not('[href*="#"]').each(function(){
                                $(this).attr("href", function(j, ahref) {
                                    ahref = ahref + '?' + utmArray[i] + '=' + utmParams(utmArray[i]) + '&';
                                    ahref = ahref.replace(/\?/g, (val, index, str) => index === str.indexOf('?') ? val : '');
                                    return ahref;
                                });
                            });
                        }
                    }
                })();
            </script>
```

Tried adding an exclusion for external links but didn't work.

```
$('a').not('[href*]').attr('rel', 'external noopener noreferrer').each(function(){
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams).
Something like this :

```js
// use:
// setUtms(location.href)

// from test:
setUtms('https://example.com?utm_campaign=foo&utm_content=bar');

function setUtms(url) {
  const needUtms = ['utm_campaign', 'utm_medium', 'utm_source', 'utm_content', 'utm_term'];
  const utms = {};
  let params = '';
  try{
    params = (new URL( url )).searchParams;
  }catch(e){
    // is not valid url
    return;
  }
  [ ...params.entries() ].forEach(( [key, value] ) => {
    if(needUtms.includes(key)){
      utms[key] = value;
    }
  });
  if(!Object.keys(utms).length){
    return;
  }
  $('a').not('[href="#"]').each(function(){
    const t = $(this);
    const href = t.attr('href');
    console.log('before: ' + href);
    let params = '';
    try{
      params = (new URL( href )).searchParams;
    }catch(e){
      // is not valid url
      return;
    }
    Object.keys(utms).forEach(key => {
      params.append(key, utms[key])
    });
    t.attr('href', href.split('?')[0] + '?' +  params.toString());
    console.log('after: ' + t.attr('href'));
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="https://example.com?foo=bar">example link</a>
```